# Invoking method depending on type in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Generic function that gets a string and parses it to the type given in T. I can make it all work except the returns. I have a bool and want to make it into a T? where T is bool.

```
public T? F<T>() where T : struct
{
   var s= GetAString();
   if(s==null) return null;
   if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
   {
      var b = bool.Parse(s);
      return ??
   } 
   if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
   {
      var i = int.Parse(s);
      return ??
   } 
    ...
}
```

return b doesn't work

return (T?)b doesn't work

return new T?(b)

Comment: I am curious as to what the code for `GetAString()` looks like

Comment: it returns a string from a config database. The key is passed as a parameter to the real method. It returns "42", "True",...  Of course the shown method will throw if the config is expected to be a bool (T = bool) and it instead contains "42" or "Foo" instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not pretty, but double-casting to `object` then to `T?` (or in this case triple-casting, since `b` is actually a `bool` and not a `bool?`) would work:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
{
  var b = bool.Parse(s);
  return (T?)(object)(bool?)b;
} 
if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
{
  var i = int.Parse(s);
  return (T?)(object)(int?)i;
}
```

However, I would generally avoid writing this kind of code. It kind of defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place. After all, if you have to write different strategies for every type parameter you might accept, it's not a *generic* solution.

---

An alternative solution would be to create 'parser' classes like this:

```
public interface IParser {
    object Parse(string s);
}

public class BoolParser : IParser {
    public object Parse(string s) {
        return bool.Parse(s);
    }
}

public class IntParser : IParser {
    public object Parse(string s) {
        return int.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

And register them statically in a dictionary like this:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, IParser> parsers = new Dictionary<Type, IParser>();
public static void Register<TResult, TParser>() 
    where TResult : struct 
    where TParser : IParser, new() 
{
    parsers.Add(typeof(TResult), new TParser());
}

...

Register<bool, BoolParser>();
Register<int, IntParser>();
```

And now you can write your `F` method like this:

```
public T? F<T>() where T : struct
{
   var s = GetAString();
   if (s == null) 
       return null;
   var t = typeof(T);
   if (parsers.ContainsKey(t))
       return (T)parsers[t].Parse(s);
   else
       throw new Exception("Specified type is not supported");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are right. I wanted to avoid duplicating code and for various other reason I need a method that returns T? (it is fitting into a T? shaped hole in the codebase)

Comment: TY - OMG that works but how to ever work it out (except via SO). I guess that why your rep is 10x mine

Comment: @pm100 Glad I could help. The `(bool?)` is needed to convert (this is technically a conversion, not a cast) from the non-nullable to a nullable type. The second `(object)` is needed to ['box' the nullable value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx), which places it on the heap. The final `(T?)` 'unboxes' it as as the generic type, which removes from the heap and verifies the type of the value. The type checker isn't smart enough to be able to verify that `(T?)b` is safe, so `(T?)(object)` effectively short-circuits the type checker.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to do 'where T: Parse()' then I could do T.Parse(s). ie a constraint that says 'T must support the static method X'. But I know these are corner cases